# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bin.strings'

Tags: python

when starting a telegram bot

```
python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tg_bot/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import database
  File "/home/tg_bot/database.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bin.strings import get_now_date
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bin.strings'



there were no errors, suddenly appeared

example from bin strings
```

def get_now_date():
"""
Получение текущей даты

```
:return:
"""
now_data = datetime.now()

return now_data.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Please translate everything that is important for the question to English.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.